# How to add class to javascript document.write & shorten date format?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript, static-block

```
<div class="shipout">
<p style="margin:0;">Delivery: FAST & FREE</p>
<script>
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
  dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
  return dat;
}

var dat = new Date();

document.write('Between ')
document.write(dat.addDays(<?php echo $_product->getData('shipout_day_from');?>))
document.write(' & ')
document.write(dat.addDays(<?php echo $_product->getData('shipout_day_to'); ?>))
</script>
</div>
```

How to add `Class` for each `document.write('Between ')`?

Output:

```
Delivery: FAST & FREE
Between Sun Mar 19 2017 06:35:17 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) & Mon Mar 20 2017 06:35:17 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Also how to shorten the date or change the date format to `Between Sun Mar 19 & Mon Mar 20`